# Using Pixel Shader 3.0 in directx

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, directx, pixel-shader

I am working with a WPF application which uses directX. I need to implement some effect using Pixel Shader 3.0. I can't use Pixel Shader 2.0 because of limitation of number of  instruction set with Pixle Shader 2.0. Can anyone tell me how to use Pixel Shader 3.0 with directX. Any help will be of great value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Have you searched on google for the answer?

Comment: Hi Nick, I am trying to implement a complex effect with Pixel Shader. My problem is the limitation of instruction set with PS Version 2.0. As my effect needs more instructions so i had to use PS 3.0. Now the problem is I am not able to use the .fx File specifying ps_3_0. directX drawing doesn't seems to be working with that .fx file. I need some help on how i can use a .fx file with PS 3.0 with directX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you'd specify your pixel shader as part of a .fx file. In that case, you'd simply mark the shader with the correct model, i.e. something like

```
technique main
{
    pass
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 myShader();
    }
}
```

Notice the `ps_3_0` there? That's how you specify the shader model.

If this is *not* how you specify your shader, please extend your question with more information on what you are doing, and what is and isn't working.

**[Edit]**
For an example of ps_3_0 shaders, see the Parrallax Occlusion Mapping sample in the DirectX SDK. The technique "RenderSceneWithPOM" is a good example.

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for answering my question. I know we can specify Pixel Shader Version 3.0 like you suggested, but the problem is with using this .fx file with directX. When I try to apply a effect with a .fx file specifying ps_3_0, drawing doesn't seems to be working. I guess there is some different way of using a pixel shader version 3.0 with directX. To make myself clear i have written a .fx file with ps_3_0, and the problem is to implement the effect with directX. It will be very helpful if you can provide some sample which can help me out.

Comment: You don't have to anything extraordinary to use ps_3_0 shaders, does it compile properly with fxc? What is your hardware like, could it be you are running an intel GMA card or some other built-in thingy that doesn't handle anything over ps2.0?

Comment: Yes I am able to compile my file with Shazzam. Also my hardware supports PS 3.0.